# Losing Form Data When Dismissing Modal

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-forms

I have a dynamically generated form which also enables the user to capture a picture from his mobile camera and set it as his profile picture. I also have a modal which has a signature-pad component which captures the signature. However, I am losing the image previously captured when I dismiss the modal. Can anybody help me out?

Here is my code.

HTML :

```
<template ngSwitchCase="profilePic">
  <div class="profile-picture">
    <center><a (click)="takePicture(field)"><img [src]="field.source"></a></center>
  </div>
</template>
```

JS for takePicture():

```
takePicture(field) {
  this.test = field;
  console.log(this.test);
  Camera.getPicture({
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    targetWidth: 1000,
    targetHeight: 1000
  }).then((ImageData) => {
    this.base64Image = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + ImageData;
    field.value = this.base64Image;
    field.source = this.base64Image;
    this.form.value[field.key] = field.source;
    this.form.controls[field.key]['_value'] = field.source;
  }, (err) => {
    // Handle error
    console.log('Cannot take picture!');
  });
}
```

and the signature-modal is here:

```
captureSignature(field) {
  this.modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ModalPage);
  this.modal.present();
  this.modal.onDismiss(data => {
    field.value = data;
    this.form.value[field.key] = field.value;
    this.form.controls[field.key]['_value'] = field.value;
  });
}
```

The modal functions are here :

```
export class ModalPage {
 @Output() saveSignature: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
 constructor(private platform: Platform, private params: NavParams, private viewCtrl: ViewController) {}
 @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;
 private signaturePadOptions: Object = {
    'canvasWidth': 520,
    'canvasHeight': 500,
  };

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.signaturePad is now available
    this.signaturePad.clear(); // invoke functions from szimek/signature_pad API
  }

  doOnEnd() {
    // will be notified of szimek/signature_pad's onEnd event
  //  console.log(this.signaturePad.toDataURL());
    return this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
    // this.saveSignature.emit(this.signaturePad.toDataURL());
    // this.exit();
  }
}
```

Comment: show some code please

Comment: @user728630 Please check the edits.

Comment: You're loosing the image because your form is dynamically generated. so everytime you open the modal, you get a new form, with an empty image field. If you want to keep the image, you have to use persistence or simply a service that would be here to keep the last picture you took.

Comment: @Supamiu But this happens only on the image field as I am able to retrieve all other data. How do I go around this?

Comment: @SreeraagMohan Can you please create a plunkr to reproduce the issue? Would be realyl easier to find out how to fix this ;)

Comment: @Supamiu I'm unable to reproduce the issue on Plunkr, sorry :/

Comment: Can you please add the `modalCtrl.create` method implementation?

Comment: @Supamiu I've added the same.